# Span tag on IE and FF

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have the following code:

```
         <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                   <ul id="controlsCar" class="entries nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                        <li data-target="#custom_carousel" data-slide-to="0">
                             <a href="#">
                                 <span>
                                     <img src="img1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive iconMenu"/>
                                 </span> 
                                 <span>
                                   <div class="menuCarusel">Tittle</div>
                                 </span>
                             </a>
                         </li>


                         <li data-target="#custom_carousel" data-slide-to="1">
                             <a href="#">
                                 <span>
                                     <img src="img2.png" alt="" class="img-responsive iconMenu"/>
                                 </span> 
                                 <span>
                                   <div class="menuCarusel">Tittle1</div>
                                 </span>
                             </a>
                         </li>
                         <li data-target="#custom_carousel" data-slide-to="2">
                             <a href="#">
                                 <span>
                                     <img src="img3.png" alt="" class="img-responsive iconMenu"/>
                                 </span> 
                                 <span>
                                   <div class="menuCarusel">Tittle3</div>
                                 </span>
                             </a>
                         </li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
```

it  resizes perfectly on Safari and Chrome but I do not see any change in the image with using FireFox or IE.

Does it have to do with the SPAN TAG ? Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: This is clearly not HTML. What is it?

Comment: sorry, its Jade, I'm using a NodeJS Server.It finally gets rendered to html.

Comment: @Gaurr I'd recommend editing this and replacing the jade with the actual rendered HTML - would make it a lot easier for people to follow and help.

Comment: You're missing a closing `</div>` - not sure if it's like that in real life or just copy/paste...But according to the HTML Validator at [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org), you're not allowed to put a div inside of a span, so given that, I'd say browser behavior is not guaranteed.